# Detecting modal dialogs in javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

Is there a way to detect when a page has been loaded in a modal dialog?  Such as when you call window.showModalDialog().

A little background: I'm trying to get around the Forms Authentication problem of the login page appearing in the modal dialog, and subsequently the rest of the site when the user logs in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For window.open you could check to see if the page you are currently on has a parent.

```
function parentExists(){
     return (window.opener != null)? true : false;
}
```

Call this when your login page loads. If it returns true, you are in a popup window (or modal). You can then close the page and redirect the parent.

It's a little more tricky for a modal box because you don't have access to the opener. First, make sure all modal boxes are opened similar to this:

```
window.showModalDialog('test.htm', self, <optional options>);
```

This will make sure something is passed into the window's arguements.

Now add the following code on your login page:

```
function parentExists()
{
    var opener = window.dialogArguments;
    return (opener == null)?false:true;
}
```

Edit: added information on modal boxes

Comment: posts obviously stay on here for a reason, so here's my 2cents...
I was also attempting to determine if a page had been loaded as modal dialog (much like what is show here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljdlgxbu.php)

but I couldn't mimic that functionality, so also attempted to check if window.opener is null, although this works, it will also return true if a link is clicked directing it to your child page. So for me, this doesn't solve the problem. 2cents end.